# P5.js drawing on a transparent background

Tags: javascript, canvas, p5.js

I'm trying to draw a few bubbles on each mouse click, and I want my canvas to be transparent so it can only display bubbles without covering rest of elements on the site.

The problem is that bubbles do not seem to move, because each of them is just mowing a little and drawing itself one more time without removing the last one.

How can I make each bubble disappear (become transparent) after moving and drawing it elsewhere?

here you can see the issue:

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrBGU.png)

oh, and here's the code:

```
var springs = [];

var Bubble = function(position) {

    this.position = position.copy();
    this.radius = random(10, 22);
    this.velocity = createVector(random(-1, 1), random(-1, 1));
    this.acceleration = random(1, 1.05);
    this.expire = random(30, 150);
};

Bubble.prototype.Move = function(){

    this.velocity = createVector(random(this.velocity.x-0.07,this.velocity.x+0.07), random(this.velocity.y-0.07,this.velocity.y+0.07));

    var wind;
    if(mouseX > windowWidth/2){
        wind = (windowWidth/2 + (mouseX - windowWidth/2))/10000.0 + 0.005;
    }else{
        wind = -1*((windowWidth/2 + (mouseX - windowWidth/2))/10000.0 + 0.005);
    }

    this.velocity.add(wind);

    this.position.add(this.velocity.mult(this.acceleration));

    this.expire -= 2;

    stroke(198, 151, 204, this.expire);
    strokeWeight(1);
    fill(255, 0);
    ellipse(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.radius, this.radius);

};

function windowResized() {
  resizeCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}

function setup() {
    createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}

function draw() {

    for(var i = 0; i < springs.length; ++i){
        var bubble = springs[i];
        if(bubble.expire > 0){
            bubble.Move();
        }else{
            springs.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }

    if (mouseIsPressed) {
        let bubble = new Bubble(createVector(mouseX, mouseY));
        springs.push(bubble);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ugh, i find the solution. Just simply use a clear() function at the top of draw function :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're just looking for the `clear()` function.

More info can be found in [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/clear).

```
// Clear the screen on mouse press.
function setup() {
  createCanvas(100, 100);
}

function draw() {
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 20, 20);
}

function mousePressed() {
  clear();
}
```

In your case, you probably want to call `clear()` as the first line in every `draw()` frame.